# Easy peasy riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> Known since the ancient times
> I'm sort of a chameleon
> Sometimes I am ugly
> And sometimes worth a million
>
> This value, however, is nothing compared
> To what I can do if not handled with care
> You use me to leave a mark on a tree
> Or to free life of impurity
>
> My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely
> But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

**Note:**

Two lines in the riddle are *extremely* vague, so that it wouldn't be too easy. :)

Comment: You said it was easy. Now You says it's hard! :P

Comment: @You That's some tricky phrasing right there. ;P

Comment: Your clues made me think of Chamillionaire, mainly because of the presence of the words "chameleon" and "million", but also "free life of impurity" - You'll never catch him ridin' dirty.  The rest doesn't really fit though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the answer

> carbon

Known since the ancient times

> carbon and its forms have been in use since ancient times

I'm sort of a chameleon
Sometimes I am ugly
And sometimes worth a million

> carbon has many forms, including charcoal graphite etc which can be described ugly and diamond which is worth millions

This value, however, is nothing compared
To what I can do if not handled with care

> might be a reference to the dangerous nature of explosives or fuels containing carbon compounds

You use me to leave a mark on a tree
Or to free life of impurity
My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely
But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

> One could use a piece of charcoal to mark a tree, charcoal is used to purify water, carbon has many forms so has a huge family, but only the lucky ones see the diamond.

**OP Commentary**

> *"...leave a mark on a tree"* was a reference to writing i.e. leaving a mark on paper.
>  *"...free life of impurity"* was a reference to graphene, which is used to filter and purify water.

Comment: Sorry about the crappy formatting,  I'm using a phone.

Comment: Charcoal is literally _made out of_ trees. ;P

Comment: @Abhishek Yes! If you don't mind, I'll just edit your answer to explain some little details I had in mind. :)

Comment: @Eutherpy please go ahead

Comment: it's forms = it is forms

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> Metal

Known since the ancient times

> People have been using metals since ancient times.

I'm sort of a chameleon

> Metals of different sorts and colors are available (A chameleon can change its colors).

Sometimes I am ugly

> Raw metal, or rusted iron is ugly

And sometimes worth a million

> Gold, platinum etc are worth millions.

This value, however, is nothing compared
To what I can do if not handled with care

> Metal machinery, if mishandled, can cause destruction of life and property.

You use me to leave a mark on a tree

> An axe can be used to leave a mark on a tree.

Or to free life of impurity

> Surgical instruments are made of metals, which can free someone's life of impurity (disease, germ)

My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely

> There are different types of metals.

But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

> Not sure about this. Probably it means that only the rich are able to afford pretty metals like gold and silver.

Comment: Close, but not it :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are:

> Oil

Known since the ancient times

> Oil was first used in ~4000 BC.

I'm sort of a chameleon

> Chameleon has a second definition as "somebody who changes opinion or behavior according to the situation" - oil can be used in many ways.

Sometimes I am ugly

> Crude oil

And sometimes worth a million

> Refined petroleum

This value, however, is nothing compared

To what I can do if not handled with care

> "it could be the fact that oil is flammable and can explode" – Peanut

You use me to leave a mark on a tree

> Pollution

Or to free life of impurity

> Many medicines are based on oil, and essential oils are, well, necessary.

My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely

> Reference to the dinosaurs, perhaps? Not sure on this one.
>  "...there are many kinds of oils like coconut oil, mustard oil, olive oil, petrol etc." - [manshu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17482/manshu)

But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

> Striking oil is rare and can be costly to refine - gotta have a lot of luck.

Comment: As for "My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely", the reasoning could be that there are many kinds of oils like coconut oil, mustard oil, olive oil, petrol etc.

Comment: @manshu You're totally right - thanks! I'll add that (and attrib) in there.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But close :)

Comment: For "This value, however, is nothing compared  To what I can do if not handled with care", it could be the fact that oil is flammable and can explode

Comment: @Peanut Added and attributed. :D

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Hackerdashi's answer, you are probably

> a **knife/blade**.

Known since the ancient times

> Knives/blades are very old tools.

I'm sort of a chameleon

> Blades take on different shapes depending on their intended use.

Sometimes I am ugly

> Open for interpretation, but ugly could be either the shape of the blade being unpleasant, or the use of a blade to do bad things.

And sometimes worth a million

> Some blades are very valuable and expensive, such as the kukri.

This value, however, is nothing compared to what I can do if not handled with care

> Knives are dangerous. Need I say more?

You use me to leave a mark on a tree

> Well, that's one way to use a blade...

Or to free life of impurity

> ...and that's another way.

My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely

> As mentioned earlier, there are lots of different kinds of blades.

But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

> Better to be on the right end of the blade. *Although, perhaps Eutherpy is being a bit dark for suggesting that using a blade for such things as "freeing life of impurity" is pretty. :P*

Comment: Haha, wrong, although the answer is dark indeed. :P

Answer (score 1):

> It's people, right?

Known since the ancient times

> People were known since then!

I'm sort of a chameleon

> This one is kind of a reach.

Sometimes I am ugly

> There are ugly people. God, are there ugly people.

And sometimes worth a million

> Ophra is a people.

This value, however, is nothing compared
To what I can do if not handled with care

> You can raise them to be more than Ophra!

You use me to leave a mark on a tree

> Family tree.

Or to free life of impurity

> Babies are considered pure, I think.

My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely

> There's a lot of people. At least a million.

But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

> A lot of them are assholes.

Comment: Who is "Ophra"?

Answer (score 0):

If one were to think more abstractly,

> perhaps language?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you explain why you think this? Answers without explanation are usually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Going more abstract:

> Industry

Known since the ancient times

> People have been industrializing forever.

I'm sort of a chameleon

> There are many forms of industry.

Sometimes I am ugly

> Gilded age, oppression of lower class by upper class.

And sometimes worth a million

> Literally a million - industry makes trillions.

This value, however, is nothing compared

To what I can do if not handled with care

> Once again, unregulated industry can have bad side-effects.

You use me to leave a mark on a tree

> Interpreting "tree" as family tree: the Morgan family, for example. Family trees were forever placed in the state of wealth.

Or to free life of impurity

> Medical industries save thousands of lives.

My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely

> Once again, industry is everywhere.

But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

> The 1% claim: only the lucky, the extremely rich get the "pretty side" of industry.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

> elements, if that's not too broad.

Known since the ancient times

> They've always existed, and in ancient times people believed in the four elements earth, fire, wind and water.

I'm sort of a chameleon

> There are many elements

Sometimes I am ugly

> They can basically take any form, so they can be ugly too.

And sometimes worth a million

> Gold, platina, etc.

This value, however, is nothing compared
To what I can do if not handled with care

> Radioactive elements can be dangerous, see Marie Curie

You use me to leave a mark on a tree

> You can make a knife or axe out of iron, for example

Or to free life of impurity

> Elements can make filters or catalysts

My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely

> 100+ elements

But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

> I guess maybe chemists, but I don't know why they would be lucky

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> Minerals

Known since the ancient times

> Have existed for billions of years

I'm sort of a chameleon

> Can blend around its surroundings

Sometimes I am ugly

> Not all are appealing to the eye

And sometimes worth a million

> Gems are minerals

This value, however, is nothing compared

To what I can do if not handled with care

> There exist a large number of fatal minerals

You use me to leave a mark on a tree

> can easily be done using any cheap mineral laying around

Or to free life of impurity

My family is huge, I can't say I'm lonely

> there are over five thousand kinds of minerals

But only the lucky see the pretty side of me.

> not everyone has the privilege to see one in front of them